# Free membership does not start before a second, paid for membership has been paid

Tags: civimember, price-sets

There is a price set with two different membership types, which both can be selected. One membership type is free, the other has to be paid for with a pay later option.

If both membership types get selected, both are part of the same contribution record. This means both change from status pending to status new, once the payment for the contribution has been received.

I would much prefer to start the free membership immediately and only the paid membership should start, once the payment has been received. - Can this somehow be configured? So far, I have not been able to find such an option.

(Currently using CiviCRM 5.13 on WordPress 5.2)

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: Just added the version information to my question. However, I would think this is rather related to Core.

Comment: Ah right. I got a solution to this, but using Drupal.https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7761/non-renewable-memberships